# Align duplicate column in excel at the same time preserving values present in subsequent column

Tags: vba, excel

My data is spreaded in many columns. In that, Column A and Column B has identical name (duplicates), while Column C to Q are values related to column B. I want to align column B to Column A while preserving subsequent values as it is.

**NOTE**: **My question is very much similar to this one "[Align identical data in two columns while preserving values in the 3rd in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883083/align-identical-data-in-two-columns-while-preserving-values-in-the-3rd-in-excel)"**

But in my case I want to preserve more subsequent columns (from C to Q). I played with code given as a solution by @Jeeped in that post but failed.

Can I get any help in this regards,

I have tried following code:
 `Sub aaMacro1()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lr As Long, vVALs As Variant
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        vVALs = Range("B1:C" & lr)
        Range("B1:C" & lr).ClearContents
        For i = 1 To lr
            For j = 1 To UBound(vVALs, 1)
                If vVALs(j, 1) = .Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                    .Cells(i, 2).Resize(1, 2) = Application.Index(vVALs, j)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub`

I have made an attempt to change range("B1:C" & lr) to range ("B1:Q" & lr), but it didnt work.
After that I have changed .Resize (1,2) to .Resize (1,3), and it copied two subsequent rows but when i inset a code with .Resize (1,4), didn't work.

Hope this edited post helps to answer my question.

With best

Comment: I'm not sure if I think stackoverflow is designed to help people who "can not write or edit code by myself". You are supposed to at least try and post the code you have tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code in the original link, should work with any number of columns ...

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub aaMacro1()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim nRows As Long, nCols As Long
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim vVALs() As Variant

    With ActiveSheet
        nRows = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        nCols = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set myRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(nRows, nCols))
    End With
    nRows = nRows - 1
    nCols = nCols - 1

    vVALs = myRng.Value
    myRng.ClearContents
    For i = 1 To nRows
        For j = 1 To nRows
            If vVALs(j, 1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
                For k = 1 To nCols
                    myRng.Cells(i, k).Value = vVALs(j, k)
                Next k
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Test input ...

[image]

Provides this output ...

[image]

Comment: Thank You @ OldUgly Script provided by you worked great for me. And @ nhouser I will surely follow your suggestion and will post the code, whever I asked new question, Best

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub AlignDupes()

Dim lRow As Long, iRow As Long
Dim mainRng As Range, sortRange As Range

With ActiveSheet
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set mainRng = .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    Set sortRange = .Range("B1:Q1").Resize(mainRng.Rows.Count)
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
End With
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=mainRng

With sortRange
    .Sort Key1:=.Cells(1, 1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    iRow = 1
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Do While iRow <= lRow
        Do While .Cells(iRow, 1) <> .Cells(iRow, 1).Offset(, -1)
            .Rows(iRow).Insert
            iRow = iRow + 1
            lRow = lRow + 1
        Loop
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop
End With

Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount

End Sub
```